# Passing paramters from rails views to jquery (gmap)

Tags: google-maps, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to use this jquery plugin in my rails3 apps
http://gmap.nurtext.de/ (Google Maps Plugin for jQuery)

It seems  very easy to use:

```
$("#map").gMap({ markers: [{ latitude: 47.660937,
                              longitude: 9.569803,
                              zoom: 6 });
```

But i have a question, how i pass the values to this jasvascript code?

something like `<%= show_map ("47.66","9.56","6") %>`

or more harcoded

```
$("#map").gMap({ markers: [{ latitude: variable1,
                              longitude: variable2,
                              zoom: variable3 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a helper function that returns a string containing the map JavaScript using the parameters you specify.

In your **app/helpers/*controllername*_helper.rb** file:

```
def show_map(lat, long, zoom)
  "$('#map').gMap({ markers: [{ latitude: #{lat}, longitude: #{long}, zoom: #{zoom} });"
end
```

Then in your view **app/views/*controllername*/*actionname***, call it using the same code you referenced in your question:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <%= show_map ("47.66","9.56","6") %>
</script>
```

Comment: just make sure you call `show_map` within `<javascript>` tags.