# Gmaps4Rails : How to open the Infowindow of the single marker by default when the Google maps is loaded (without clicking on the marker)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, gmaps4rails

I am using Gmaps4Rails in my rails application for loading google maps. Everything works fine.
I have a single marker and I want to keep the infowindow open by default when the google map is loaded (without clicking on the marker).
Please help me how to achieve this using Gmaps4Rails gem?

I have tried the following snippet of code but it doesn't work.

```
<% content_for :scripts do %>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
      if (Gmaps.map.markers.length == 1) {

        var marker = Gmaps.map.markers[0];
        var infowindow = marker.infowindow;
        infowindow.open(Gmaps.map.map, marker);
        <%#*alert("Gmaps info open");%>
      }
    }
  </script>
<% end %>
```

This was the solution mentioned by apneadiving in [How do I make an infowindow automatically display as open with Google-Maps-for-Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774664/how-do-i-make-an-infowindow-automatically-display-as-open-with-google-maps-for-r)

Thanks for you help and support.

Comment: what error do you get? what does 'it does not work' means?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

> infowindow.open(Gmaps.map.map, marker);

Try

> infowindow.open(Gmaps.map.map, marker.serviceObject);

I was also having trouble getting the infowindow to open and that seems to work for me.